# How to implement previous and next button using ajax in mvc?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am building an online test webapp in asp.net mvc4.And I need to make the user to navigate between previous and next questions (only 1 question at a time). I have a layout which has a countdown timer in it. I have a question & options list as a model in the view and I need to navigate the list via previous and next buttons. The layout must remain same since it has a timer in it. When the user clicks on 'next', the current question should get back to list along with chosen answer (via radio buttons) and the next question from the list should be displayed. Similar function is done by previous button also. Can anyone please suggest a solution in Ajax,Json or Javascript ?

The view:StartTest

```
@model LoginTrial3.Models.QuestionPaper

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "StartTest";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_LayoutTest.cshtml";
}

<h2>StartTest</h2>
```

Model : QuestionPaper

```
public class QuestionPaper
    {
        public List<object> RandomQuestionList = new List<object>();
        //generate the maps to hold the answers
        public Dictionary<int, string> AptiAnsList = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        public Dictionary<int, string> TechAnsList = new Dictionary<int, string>();

        //define a ctor
        public QuestionPaper(List<object> QList)
        {
            foreach(var item in QList)
            {
                RandomQuestionList.Add(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

each object in QList is of a AptiQuestionType :

```
public class AptiQuestion
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public string OptionA { get; set; }
        public string OptionB { get; set; }
        public string OptionC { get; set; }
        public string ExpectedAnswer { get; set; }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution without ajax could be to extend the model class and add ids of the previous and next items, then in the view render links using these ids.